# Why do I get an error when resolving hostname under Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, dns

In Ubuntu 12.04(Virtual Box) I am trying to resolve a hostname by using

```
nslookup myhost 172.16.0.100
```

and I get the reply

```
Server:     172.16.0.100
Address:    172.16.0.100#53

** server can't find esy-buildserver: SERVFAIL
```

where the IP `100.16.0.100` is the adress of an internal company DNS server. Any internet connection from the Linux box to the outside world just works as usual (can `ping google.com` for example).

On the windows machine, where the virtual box with Ubuntu 12.04 is running, I do (on the command line)

```
nslookup myhost
```

and I get the correct IP adress, *including* the IP of the DNS server, which is 172.16.0.100!!

Why does the command `nslookup` work under Windows but not under Linux?

**Additional information:**

- `ipconfig` on the windows machine (only in German - is it possible to change this to English?)

  ```
  Ethernet-Adapter LAN-Verbindung 2:

  Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

  Ethernet-Adapter LAN-Verbindung:

  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: myhost.ch
  Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::1b2:42a7:102e:3e9
  IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.5.16
  Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.5.1

  Ethernet-Adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
  Verbindungslokale IPv6-Adresse  . : fe80::c1a3:5518:996e:5f
  IPv4-Adresse  . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
  Subnetzmaske  . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
  Standardgateway . . . . . . . . . :

  Tunneladapter isatap.myhost.ch:

  Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix: myhost.ch

  Tunneladapter 6TO4 Adapter:

  Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

  Tunneladapter isatap.{555CF642-7F0F-458A-BF05-81F5684C23D1}:

  Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:

  Tunneladapter isatap.{CAC63733-325B-44F7-AC88-D6649B265470}:

  Medienstatus. . . . . . . . . . . : Medium getrennt
  Verbindungsspezifisches DNS-Suffix:
  ```
- `route print -4`

  ```
  ===========================================================================
  Schnittstellenliste
  15...00 ff 55 5c f6 42 ......TeamViewer VPN Adapter
  11...e8 39 35 4e 73 16 ......Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
  19...08 00 27 00 04 f7 ......VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter
  13...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-6zu4-Adapter
  14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #2
  16...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft-ISATAP-Adapter #3
  ===========================================================================

  IPv4-Routentabelle
  ===========================================================================
  Aktive Routen:
  Keine
  Ständige Routen:
  Keine
  ```
- `ifconfig` on the Linux box

  ```
  eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:68:66:59
          inet addr:172.16.5.170  Bcast:172.16.5.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe68:6659/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:27955 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15874 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:15451204 (15.4 MB)  TX bytes:2747503 (2.7 MB)

  lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:575 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:52064 (52.0 KB)  TX bytes:52064 (52.0 KB)
  ```

Comment: Thansk for spotting this. Its all 100.16.0.100

Comment: How is your VM connected to the network, via bridge or NAT adapter?

Comment: It looks like the virtual machine (Ubuntu) is connected to its host (Windows) by a bridge.

Comment: sorry, you will have to be more precise. can you post the routing table of the windows machine? output of ipconfig  and route print -4

Comment: you can use http://translate.google.com for translation

Comment: But even then the terms will not be translated into the exact terms used in an English installation.

Comment: Did you actually try on the Linux VM: `nslookup myhost @172.16.0.100`?

Comment: @Alex: *It looks like [...] connected [...] by a bridge.* Why do you say it so vague? Is it connected in bridge mode or not? Are you not sure about how the connection is made?

Comment: @Alex Can you please call `ifconfig` on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Keith: Please see my question which includes the answer to your question.

Comment: Question updated with `ifconfig`.

Comment: Can you ping the DNS server?

Comment: From the Linux box I am able to ping the address 172.16.0.100.